# How to acces user detail in template in django

Tags: django, django-templates

I want check whether logged in  user is doctor or patient i tried the following method to check that thing,but did not succeed can any one help me.

[model.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3PeA.png)

[forms.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REoig.png)

[index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yW2o.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMrxP.png)

or what does this error means:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '=='Doctor'' from 'user.user_type=='Doctor''
```

Comment: could you put this part ```user.user_type``` in an ```html``` tag and then report back the output.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have spaces around `==`. It should be `user.user_type == 'Doctor'` instead of `user.user_type=='Doctor'`

Looks like you also have a typo in index.html.

Change `user.user_type=='Pateint'` to `user.user_type == 'Patient'`. Note the spaces around `==`.

Answer (score 0):

use this , because tab it's %s as Strings

```
user.user_type == 'Doctor'

user.user_type == 'Patient'
```